# Where is the proper place to attach for catching ALL ASP.NET MVC errors?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, unhandled-exception

I'm adding error handling for our asp.net mvc 3 application. Basically I want to catch every unhandled error short of a nuclear meltdown.

I've identified the following spots for doing this:

- `OnException` in the controller base class (all my controllers derive from the same base class so it's feasible)
- `HandleErrorAttribute` with a custom view that handles the exception
- `Application_Error` event in `Global.asax`
- Turn on `<customErrors mode="On">` in web.config and set a custom URL which will handle the exception.

I have a very vague idea on how these places relate between themselves and would like for someone to explain what the differences are and why there are so many of them in the first place.

Also, which one (or all?) should I use? Are some of them redundant? Are there exceptions that can be caught by one but not by others? And what happens if even those all fail (like, the very last-resort exception handler method trows an exception itself)?

Answer (score 1):

- OnException in the base controller will not catch all errors
  (specially if not all of your controllers inherit from it).
- HandleErrorAttribute will need you to apply the attribute individually everywhere. Or apply it using a Global Filter but it will be the same for all controllers.
- Turning customErrors off will just display the error, not handle it. And you can't server a different view for different types of errors.

What we usually do is this:

Install ELMAH or similar package to keep track of all your errors, even when they occur silently.

Then, in global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Retrieving the last server error
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();

    //Erases any buffered HTML output
    Response.Clear();

    var httpException = exception as HttpException;

    var routeData = new RouteData();
    routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error"); //Adding a reference to the error controller
    if (httpException == null)
    {
        routeData.Values.Add("action", "ServerError"); //Non HTTP related error handling
    }

    else //It's an Http Exception, Let's handle it.
    {
        switch (httpException.GetHttpCode())
        {
            case 401:
            case 403:
                //Forbidden page.
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "Forbidden");
                break;
            case 404:
                //Page not found.
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "NotFound");
                break;
            case 500:
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "ServerError");
                break;
            default:
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index");
                break;
        }
    }

    //Pass exception details to the target error View.
    routeData.Values.Add("message", exception);

    //Clear the error on server.
    Server.ClearError();

    //Avoid IIS7 getting in the middle
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

    // Call target Controller and pass the routeData.
    IController errorController = new ErrorController();
    errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(
         new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
}
```

We feel this is the option that gives us most control on handling and what to show our visitors. Each of the actions shown (servererror, notfound and forbidden) have a different screen and depending if the server is running on debug or release then we show the stack trace information or not (but we always capture it with ELMAH so we can always just see it there)

Comment: Elmah is great, but there are some pitfalls - it won't catch WCF service errors, as well as StackOverflowException and OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar - StackOverflow and OutOfMemory are pretty much unrecoverable anyway, so it's OK if those are not caught.

Comment: My controllers do all inherit from the same class, and I am looking for a global solution. So why are there the `OnException` and `HandleErrorAttribute` if I can do everything in `Application_Error` already? And what's the point of having two places for redirects (`customErrors` and `HandleErrorAttribute`)?

Comment: I think it's this: customErrors is there since ASP.NET started with WebForms, when the exception happens IIS catches it and just redirects you to a specific page. HandleErrorAttribute allows you to catch the error and then decide what to do with it: either manage it, re-throw it, or just simply redirect the user to another page (which is what customError does)